# How do I edit multiple projects in a single session in Android Studio?

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

I have a library projectA that I publish to my local maven repo, which is a dependency for my main projectB. I would like to have projectB open in Android Studio, perhaps command-click a class that lives in projectA, and instead of seeing uneditable code, I would be able to make changes to that code.

Currently, I have to open projectA, make the changes, publish to maven local, and hope the changes are seen in project B when I switch back to it.

How can I edit both projects in the same session?

Comment: Have you tried to add the library project as new module to your app project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In project B, you can look at the decompiled project A code via command-click as you mentioned. However, when you're looking at the decompiled project B's code, you should see the following at the top bar.

[image]

Select `Choose Sources...` and point to project A's source directory. Once that's done, you can start editing project A's code, you'd see the following:

[image]

You'd still need to rebuild project A's code for the changes to reflect in project B's build.

There's a couple other nuances with this approach. For example, switching branches in project A will cause the sources to be detached in project B I believe.